# Navigate from one fragment to another when using MVVM pattern for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-mvvm

- I am creating an app using MVVM pattern.I am using **Navigation Graph** to manage fragments in my app and as per the recommended approach we don't have to put UI logic inside **Activity/Fragments** but in **Viewmodel** .
- So my question is how to navigate from one fragment to another. I know this can be done directly inside fragment using `navController.navigate(R.id.action_here)` but how would I handle navigation from the ViewModel on button press?.

My code:

> IntroViewModel.kt

```
class IntroViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun onBtn1Pressed(view: View) {
        Log.d(IntroViewModel::class.java.simpleName, ": onBtn1Pressed")
    }

    fun onBtn2Pressed(view: View) {
        Log.d(IntroViewModel::class.java.simpleName, ": onBtn2Pressed ")
    }
}
```

> IntroFragment.kt:

```
class IntroFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: IntroViewModel
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var introBinding: IntroFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        introBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.intro_fragment, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(IntroViewModel::class.java)
        introBinding.introModel = viewModel
        return introBinding.root;
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

    }
}
```

> intro_fragment.xml:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="introModel"
        type="example.com.viewmodel.IntroViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16dp"
    tools:context=".fragments.IntroFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Choose one " />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_"
        android:onClick="@{introModel::onBtn1Pressed}"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:text="Btn1" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{introModel::onBtn2Pressed}"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/btn_1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/btn_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:text="Btn2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: would it break your design choice's rules to put an instance of NavController in your ViewModel and initialize it in `onViewCreated()` so that the ViewModel could handle navigation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Navigating from inside the `ViewModel` would mean you need an instance of the view which goes against the concept of MVVM. Instead, use a `LiveData` to indicate to your fragment that it needs to navigate to the next destination. you can use the following `Event` class (from one of Google's [architecture-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/Event.kt)) to make sure the navigation is only fired once.

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Use it with this `Observer`:

```
/**
 * An [Observer] for [Event]s, simplifying the pattern of checking if the [Event]'s content has
 * already been handled.
 *
 * [onEventUnhandledContent] is *only* called if the [Event]'s contents has not been handled.
 */
class EventObserver<T>(private val onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
            onEventUnhandledContent(it)
        }
    }
}
```

This is your `LiveData`:

```
private val _openTaskEvent = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
val openTaskEvent: LiveData<Event<String>> = _openTaskEvent
```

And finally you can observer it as so:

```
viewModel.openTaskEvent.observe(this, EventObserver {
    //Do your navigation here
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer (Thanks to Mohamed Mohsin ):

> IntroViewModel.kt:

```
class IntroViewModel : ViewModel() {

  private val _navigateScreen = MutableLiveData<Event<Any>>()
  val navigateScreen: LiveData<Event<Any>> = _navigateScreen

    fun onBtn1Pressed(view: View) {
       _navigateScreen.value = Event(R.id.action_here)
    }

    fun onBtn2Pressed(view: View) {
        _navigateScreen.value = Event(R.id.action_here)
    }
}
```

> Event.kt:

```
    open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */

    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}

class EventObserver<T>(private val onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
            onEventUnhandledContent(it)
        }
    }
}
```

> IntroFragment.kt:

```
class IntroFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: IntroViewModel
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var introBinding: IntroFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        introBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.intro_fragment, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(IntroViewModel::class.java)
        introBinding.introModel = viewModel
        return introBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        viewModel.navigateScreen.observe(activity!!, EventObserver {
            navController.navigate(it)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the id of your next destination when using `navController.navigate()`. you can find the id in you `nav_graph.xml`. example: `navController.navigate(R.id.detailFragment)`.

Comment: Then how would I know which button was pressed!

Comment: Okay in that case, change `Event<Any>` to `Event<Int>` since you're passing an resource id. and make sure the id passed (like R.id.action_here) is an actual id of a destination in the `nav_graph`

Comment: change `navController.navigate(viewModel.navigateScreen.value)` to `navController.navigate(it)`.